# xsl:key how to select unmatched key values

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to compare two xml using xsl:key, but not sure how to print unmatched keys. In this scenario I am keying b.xml and comparing with a.xml, but it does not print unmatched keys from b.xml.

a.xml

```
<root>
<metas>
    <meta>
        <name>x</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </meta>
    <meta>
        <name>y</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </meta>
    <meta>
        <name>z</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </meta>
</metas>
```

b.xml

```
<root>
<metas>
    <info>
        <name>a</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </info>
    <info>
        <name>y</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </info>
    <info>
        <name>z</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </info>
</metas>
```

Desired output:

```
    Table

                a.xml               b.xml
    name        missing in a.xml    a
    value       missing in a.xml    0

    name        x                   missing in b.xml
    value       0                   missing in b.xml

    name        y                   y
    value       1                   1

    name        z                   z
    value       1                   1
```

My xsl;

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:param name="uri" as="xs:string" select="'b.xml'"/>
<xsl:param name="b" as="document-node()" select="doc($uri)"/>
<xsl:key name="bCompare" match="root/metas/info" use="name"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <th>a.xml</th>
                    <th>b.xml</th>
                </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>                    
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="metas">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="meta">        
    <xsl:variable name="compare" select="key('bCompare', name, $b)"/>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>             
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$compare/name"/>
            <xsl:if test="empty($compare/name)">missing in b.xml</xsl:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Value</th>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$compare/value"/>
            <xsl:if test="empty($compare/value)">missing in b.xml</xsl:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a key for the other direction as well, i.e. `<xsl:key name="aCompare" match="root/metas/meta" use="name"/>`, then you need to make sure you process those elements of the second document with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/><xsl:apply-templates select="$b//info/meta[not(name = key('bCompare', $main-doc//meta/name, $main-doc))]"/>` and then you need a template

```
<xsl:template match="info">        
    <xsl:variable name="compare" select="key('aCompare', name, $main-doc)"/>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$compare/name"/>
            <xsl:if test="empty($compare/name)">missing in a.xml</xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>             
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Value</th>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$compare/value"/>
            <xsl:if test="empty($compare/value)">missing in a.xml</xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```